# pylab install error gcc windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, gcc, pip, windows-10, theano

So I recently installed Theano on a python 2.7 environment within Anaconda 3, on windows 10. Theano passed `theano.test()` at least. I am using example code from [deeplearning.net](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html). I heva sucessfully run the first block on the linked page which defines a Theano function. When I go to install pylab via `pip install pylab` so that I can use skimage for the second block, my installer quits while doing some gcc call for the portion that looks like it says "shared geometry". One thing I noticed right away is the `-DEBUG` flag is misspelled `-DDEBUG`. Could this be the cause? Does it have something to do with `msvcr90.dll` and if so what is that and what do I need to do about it? Also, probably important, I'm using a slightly (6 months or so) outdated TDM-GCC which is 4.9 something. Here is the line in question, as well as a few others that might be interesting:

```
`copying skimage\_shared\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\skimage\_shared\tests
running build_ext
Looking for python27.dll
Cannot build msvcr library: "msvcr90d.dll" not found
customize Mingw32CCompiler
customize Mingw32CCompiler using build_ext
building 'skimage._shared.geometry' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\skimage
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\skimage\_shared
compile options: '-DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x0900 -I"C:\Users\USE DIS\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Users\USE DIS\Anaconda3\envs\py27\include" -I"C:\Users\USE DIS\Anaconda3\envs\py27\PC" -c'
gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x0900 -I"C:\Users\USE DIS\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Users\USE DIS\Anaconda3\envs\py27\include" -I"C:\Users\USE DIS\Anaconda3\envs\py27\PC" -c skimage\_shared\geometry.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\skimage\_shared\geometry.o
Found executable C:\Users\USE DIS\Anaconda3\envs\py27\Scripts\gcc.bat
'C:\Users\USE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error: Command "gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DNPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR -D__MSVCRT_VERSION__=0x0900 -I"C:\Users\USE DIS\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Users\USE DIS\Anaconda3\envs\py27\include" -I"C:\Users\USE DIS\Anaconda3\envs\py27\PC" -c skimage\_shared\geometry.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\skimage\_shared\geometry.o" failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

Comment: -D<name> is an option that overrides an imported environment variable.  You can see it used in other places.  The command line is overriding variables DEBUG, NPY_MINGW_USE_CUSTOM_MSVCR, and __MSVCRT_VERSION__

Comment: Still haven't quite figured this one out yet but pylab and skimage work enough for me to keep testing out Theano on the site tutorial.